# ASP.NET 5: Create a Unit Test project referencing a Web Class Library (Package)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, asp.net5

I am using ASP.NET 5 and I have the following projects:
- ASP.NET Web Application: Here I have everything related to UI)
- Web Class Library (Package): Here I have the business layer and database access.

Now I want to add a unit test project in order to test some logic I am starting to write in the Web Class Library project. But when I create a new Unit Test Project, I am unable to reference the Web Class Library project from it, because the Web Class Library project doesn't have a dll as output.

I don't want to reference the dll created under \artifacts\bin\theProjectCore\Debug\dnx451 because I think it is cleaner to reference the project directly (as I always did before).

When I try to add a reference to the project, the error I get is that the project I am referencing has not a .dll or .exe as output. This is because the new Web Class Library project is designed to be distributable via NuGet package.

Thanks in advance!

Gonzalo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to this, what I have done is to set the web class library project to generate output on build (this is an option under the project properties) and then I created a test project referencing that output. On each build the output is updated and the test project is always referencing the latest code build.

Although I don't think this is ideal, since I would like to reference the project and have Microsoft take care about this, I think there is no other way of doing this so far. Is someone knows about a better way, please let me know :).

Thanks!